# How do I set up a route for a form inside a landing page section in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, controller, routes

The website I'm working on is one continuous landing page with sections pulled in via blade pages and elements. How do I route a contact form in one of the landing page sections to a controller I've built?

I've built a controller that will send an email to my site administrator and also display a success notification to the user submitting the form. Right now, I've built the form on its own view ('example.com/contact'). Everything works appropriately when using the view. But I don't know how to get the landing page URL for the production contact form ('example.com/#contact') to route to the same (or any) controller.

```
@section('content')

@include('layouts.partials._header')

@include('pages.elements._about')

<div class="separator-line separator-primary"></div>

@include('pages.elements._calendar')

<div class="separator-line separator-primary"></div>

@include('pages.elements._contact') <!--form is pulled in here-->

@endsection
```

current web route that works with a separate view:

```
   Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('pages.landing');
   });
   Route::get('/contact', 'ContactController@show');
   Route::post('/contact', 'ContactController@mailToAdmin');
```

Controller I'm trying to route the form to:

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{


    public function mailToAdmin(ContactFormRequest $message, Admin $admin)
    {
        $admin->notify(new InboxMessage($message));
        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Thanks for the message! We will get back to you soon!');
    }
}
```

example of my form:

```
<div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="/contact">
            {{ csrf_field() }} 
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your name" name="name" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email: </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="john@example.com" name="email" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">message: </label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control luna-message" id="message" placeholder="Type your messages here" name="message" required></textarea>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send">Send</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Probably it's me, but I did not understand the question, can you please help me and rework a bit the question?

Comment: if I can, yes. The question, in a nutshell, is how do I get a contact form to route to a PostController when it does not have its own view?

Comment: The code above shows the landing page code (each section broken into its own blade.php file and then rendered) and where the form is pulled in. Second segment of code is the my current web routes code. Third segment is my controller that sends an email when the form is submitted.

Comment: Do you want to use the same form with different action route?

Comment: yes. I want the form to use POST, not GET.

Comment: Pleas add an example of your form

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the route to the "action" attribute of the form tag.
Use:

```
<form action: "{{URL::to('/contact')}}" method:"POST">
```